# RewriteRule in RewriteRule

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

I need help with nginx, to create a rule in the url

I have this route:
"/site/assets/523917fe/example.js"

but I need the nginx to interpret it

location / {

```
      index index.php;

      try_files $uri /site/frontend/web/index.php$is_args$args;

       rewrite ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 break;
    }
```

since this is the real path:
"/site/frontend/web/assets/523917fe/example.js"

Thank you